# Is there a way to do String.Format() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string.format

So I have a client who does not allow any server side coding, except in rare occurences classic asp, so everything is HTML and javascript.

So basically I need to build a URL from the form and then redirect.  Javascript isn't necessarily my thing, but this would take me 5 minutes in asp.net using String.Format.

Is there a String.Format method in javascript?

Comment: You need to do something to teach your client that his all-javascript model is just **wrong**.

Comment: It's more like saying "Let's take a **leaky** boat" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ouch, that sucks.

Stolen from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery):

```
String.format = function() {
  var s = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {       
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
    s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
  }

  return s;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean String.prototype.format so that you can use it as "a {1} test".format("quick");

Comment: Obviously he didn't mean that as the string is quite clearly the first argument but in most situations prototyping would be a better option.

Comment: True, you could use prototyping. The reasoning here is simply that c# (my language of choice) works in this manner. Personal preference though, prototyping would work fine too.

Answer (score 0):

no, there's no such thing in javascript, but some people have already written a printf for js

e.g [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing and settled on Prototype's "Template" object.

From the Prototype [examples](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Template/)

// the template (our formatting expression)
var myTemplate = new Template(
 'The TV show #{title} was created by #{author}.');

// our data to be formatted by the template
var show = {
  title: 'The Simpsons',
  author: 'Matt Groening',
  network: 'FOX'
};

// let's format our data
myTemplate.evaluate(show);
// -> "The TV show The Simpsons was created by Matt Groening."