# jQuery dynamically create table/tr/td or etc and append attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, refactoring

In an example I am having this structure (small example):

```
<table id=example>
<tr class="blah test example"><td>Test1</td><td><a href="url">LINK</a>Test11</td></tr>
<tr class="blah test example"><td>Test2</td><td><a href="url">LINK</a>Test22</td></tr>
<tr class="blah test example"><td>Test3</td><td><a href="url">LINK</a>Test33</td></tr>
</table>
```

In jQuery I would create it dynamically like:

```
var test = "<table id=" + someIDVar + ">"
           + "<tr class=" + classOneVar 
+ classTwoVar + classThreeVar + ">"....
```

and etc etc... (lots of other stuff to write). After I would just append it:

```
$(".somePlaceInHtml").append(test);
```

So is there any other way to write such a structure dynamically with jQuery? This is a problem for me because I am having a big structure, not as small as I showed in the example. The main reason is I want to get better readability for myself and other developers who will maintain this code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can you make a "template" out of your string? If yes, then store it in a "constant" variable (e.g. defined in global scope), containing placeholders for actual variables, like `{0}`, `{1}` etc, as you would use it in C#'s `string.format()` method.

So, you would have code like this:

```
var rowTemplate = "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>SomePredefinedText {1}</td></tr>";
var alternateRowTemplate = "<tr><td class='a'>{0}</td><td>SomewhatDifferent {1}</td></tr>";
 ...... somewhere deep in your code
 $("#someElement").append(
        rowTemplate.format("myvalue1", "myvalue2")
       ).append(
        alternateRowTemplate.format("myvalue3", "myvalue4")
       );
```

You would then use the string.format implementation as per this answer: [Equivalent of String.format in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery/1038930#1038930)

Answer (score 28):

Here's a simplified example:

```
  $(function() {
    var tbl = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "bob" });
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(tbl);
    $('<td></td>').text("text1").appendTo(row);
    $('<td></td>').text("Test22").prepend($('<a></a>').attr({ href: "#" }).text("LINK")).appendTo(row);        
    tbl.appendTo($(".somePlaceInHtml"));        
  });
```

Wrap the row portion in a loop, replace with variables and it's at least easier to maintain/read in my opinion, but I'm used to jQuery, so your mileage may vary, just an option.

A side note, since this is using `.text()` everywhere, it helps prevents cross-site scripting attacks within your output as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a StringBuilder, much like the one in C#. Here's a snippet took from [Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/):

```
$.stringBuilder = function() {
    this.buffer = [];
};

$.stringBuilder.prototype = {

    cat: function(what) {
        this.buffer.push(what);
        return this;
    },

    string: function() {
        return this.buffer.join('');
    }
};
```

This way, you can have the following code:

```
var html = new $.stringBuilder();
for (var i in data)
    html.cat("<tr><td>").cat(i).cat("</td><td></tr>");

$('#element').append(html.string());
```

The benefit of this approach is that you'll have fast concatenation (array joins perform better under IE6), and you could extend the object with other useful function (say, `catIf` that takes a boolean expression, or `rep` that repeats a given string several times).

Comment: Array joins *were* faster in IE6. In present browsers, the speed is approximately the same - sometimes string concatenation is faster, sometimes array joining. See my benchmarks here: http://tips.naivist.net/2010/01/19/string-concatenation-versus-array-join-in-javascript/

Comment: note taken! thanks - and here's one more article that I found on the subject: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fastest-way-to-build-an-html-string/ - seems that the join is best ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could instead of concatenating strings together so make use of the [array.join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function.

```
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      arr[i] = "<tr>" + sth + "</tr>";       
    }

node.innerHTML = arr.join('');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("id", "submit_bttn");
    btn.style.width = 125 + "px";
    btn.style.height = 50 + "px";
    btn.innerHTML = "Submit";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    var x = document.getElementById("submit_bttn");
    x.onclick = function(){
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Golak, welcome to SO. Some descriptive text to your code would be nice!

Comment: Good answer, pure javascript one though, not jquery.