# How to create a td object jquery

Tags: jquery, new-object

I'm searching a way to create a td by object methode and not by creating a html element that tranform in object

So I'm searching a way to make some thing like
my_td = $('td');
my_td = new $('td');

Actualy when I do this all my td are modified by that one 
what I'm trying to do:

```
tab += '<tr>';
tab += '<td>'+Id+'</td>';
tab += '</tr>';
```

what I wouldlike to do is some thing like

```
tab.('tr').('td').text(ID);
```

Is there anyway?
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the .append() function?

Comment: Check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363030/9456405

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `self-closed` element like below

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

```js
var my_td = $('<td/>');

console.log(my_td.get(0))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks and how to add the tr before? because I tried $('<tr>').('<td>') but it didn't work

Comment: Try `$('<tr/>').append(my_td)`