# JS string formatting operation - substitute a variable value to string

Tags: javascript

In python & other programming languages there's a way to substitute a variable's value in between  a string easily, like this,

```
name="python"
a="My name is %s"%name
print a
>>>My name is python
```

How do I achieve this in java-script? The plain old string concatenation is very complex for a large string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String.Format in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534803/string-format-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no native way to do that. In javascript, you do:

```
var name = 'javascript';
var a = 'My name is ' + name;
console.log(a);

>>>My name is javascript
```

Otherwise, if you really would like to use a string formatter, you could use a library.
For example, https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

With `sprintf` library:

```
var name = 'javascript';
sprintf('My name is %s', name);

>>>My name is javascript
```

Comment: console.log does string formatting/substitution.
var myobject = {foo:'bar',x: 'y'};
console.log("myobject = %o", myobject);

console.log("foo = %s", myobject.foo);

Answer (score 23):

It's 2017, we have [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
var name = "javascript";
console.log(`My name is ${name}`);
// My name is javascript
```

It uses **back-tick** not **single quote**.

You may find this question and answers also useful.
[JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: It should be accepted answer, but the question was asked 5 years ago.

Comment: I love this answer, but we unfortunately live in a world a ton of pre-ES6 code out there, and this is ES6 and beyond, no?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). They have sugar like in ruby

```rb
name = "javascript"
a = "My name is #{name}"
console.log a
# >>> My name is javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in javascript, so the only way to achieve this is concatenation. Also another way could be replacing particular values with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Using Node, this should work.

```
[terryp@boxcar] ~  :: node
> var str = 'string substitute!';
> console.log('This is a %s', str);
This is a string substitute!
>
```