# Change variable inside js string

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the following line:

$("<ul><li><a  href="+url">"+displayName + "</a>"+"<br>"+description+"</br></li></ul>".appendTo(".results")

into the next string:

$("<ul><li><a  href={0}> {1}" + "</a>"+"<br>"+description+"</br></li></ul>",{0:url, 1:displayName}.appendTo(".results").

**however, instead of displayName i get 1.
please help to fix this**
**As you can see i've tried to write it like in c#**

Comment: looks a little like string.format from c#, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534803/use-of-string-format-in-javascript

Comment: if you have ES6 then you can use string interpolation

Comment: Please format your question better it's hardly legible.

Comment: i tried format by myself but, even this code at question is messed up, the tags are made with html symbols

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 string interpolation, it would look like this:

```js
$(`
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=${url}> ${displayName}</a>
      <br>${description}</br>
    </li>
  </ul>
`).appendTo(".results");
```

Notice the back-ticks instead of double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you but itsstill show the word displayName and not the Name of the item