# C#-like String.Format() function in JQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery

Is it possible to call a C#-like String.Format() function in JQuery?

Comment: Are you use the ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: look at this question [Equivalent of String.format in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

Comment: @Serghei I'd like to apply the best of each technology around my works. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Equivalent of String.format in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

> Here is the format function...
>
> ```
> String.format = function() {
>   var s = arguments[0];
>   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {       
>     var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
>     s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
>   }
>
>   return s;
> }
> ```

Comment: Had to change a couple of lines otherwise it malfunctioned when one of the arguments was null:
var replacement = arguments[i + 1];
s = s.replace(reg, replacement == null ? "" : replacement);

Answer (score 12):

Checkout [format()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/) that's part of the validation plugin that does C# like string formatting.

Comment: The link was broken, so I fixed it.

Comment: +1 because although it's not purely javascript, it's a better option than a custom script if one is already using jquery.validate