# jQ Format is not a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this error when on this line when I'm formatting a string using jQuery,
`Uncaught TypeError: f.format is not a function`

This is the line where the error seems to be appearing (I've got multiple lines using the same method but none of these seem to be working)

```
var $li = $(f.format(betid, bet.amount, bet.icon, bet.name, bet.amount));
```

Why is this happening? I've used this before and it worked just fine?

String:

```
var f = "<div>";
f += "<div class='avatar''>";
f += "<img src='{2}'>";
f += "</div>";
f += "<div>{3}</div>";
var num = bet.amount;
f += "<div class='user-bet ng-binding'>" + num + "</div>";
f += "</div></div>";
```

Comment: and `f` would be...?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `f` is...

Comment: Could you post more code, please? We need to see `f`.

Comment: Just a long string using {1} {2} etc.

Edited post^

Comment: AFAIK there's no native ".format" method on Javascript strings. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp Are you missing a plugin?

Comment: Well, yeah, `f` is a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), which does not have a format method. Are you confusing this with .NET?

Comment: As a reference, [here are the methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2) that belong to a string in JavaScript...

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I'm an inbicile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.format` is not a function in Javascript

You can write such a function however:

> ```
> String.prototype.format = function() {
>   var str = this;
>   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {       
>     var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
>     str = str.replace(reg, arguments[i]);
>   }
>   return str;
> }
> ```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956384/c-like-string-format-function-in-jquery)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using jQuery as well?

Comment: @MartinDev Doesn't matter. You're calling `.format()` on the string not a jQuery object.

Comment: That was it, I usually put this code in the head of my pages, I completely forgot about it this time. Thank you for the anwser tho, I'll accept this as an anwser but it was my own fault.