# replace span text with a string with jquery

Tags: jquery

in below code if i replace `temp` in `$(this).text(temp);` with `"something"` it works and change `span` text, but when i use a `string.format` it doesn't work.

`jquery code:`

```
  var x = $("span.resource");           
  x.each(function () {            
       if ($(this).attr('id') = "l1") {
           var temp = String.Format("{0}/{1}", variable1,variable2);
           $(this).text(temp);
       });
```

Comment: Where does `variable1` and `variable2` come from?

Comment: You might find [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format) useful , also you might find much more efficient to find the element with the `id=l1` using `$('#l1')`

Comment: Also, if you take a look at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) there's no method named `Format` for the `String` object. Are you perhaps confusing languages? ;)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall  variables define global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) there's no method named `Format` for the `String` object. My guess is that you are confusing languages (JavaScript and C#), which is quite common for multi-language developers.

However, everything's not lost. You can easily recreate an equivalent method in JavaScript by adding to the prototype of the `String` object. Credits go to gpvos, Josh Stodola, infinity and Julian Jelfs who contributed to [these solutions to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery).

```
String.prototype.format = function(){
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) { return args[n]; });
};
```

With a little tweaking it should work like this:

```
$("span.resource").each(function(){
    if (this.id == "l1") {
        var $this = $(this),
            newText = $this.text().format(var1, var2);
        $this.text(newText);
    }
});
```

Blair Mitchelmore have a [similar implementation on his blog](http://blairmitchelmore.com/javascript/string.format), but with some extra features and added functionality. You might want to check that out as well!

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax errors, and String.Format doesn't exist in javascript. This works:

```
  $("span.resource").each(function () {             
       if ($(this).attr('id') == "l1") {
           var temp = variable1 + '/' + variable2;
           $(this).text(temp);
       }
  });
```