# Do we have something like C# String.Format(...) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Do we have something like C# String.Format(...) in JavaScript?

I like to be able to say String.Format('text text {0}, text text {1}', value1, value2);

and ideally as an extension method:

'text text {0}, text text {1}'.format(value1, value2);

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

here is your solution:

```
String.format = function() {
  var s = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {       
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
    s = s.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
  }

  return s;
}
```

more informations here => [Equivalent of String.format in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

Comment: How is it possible to have the format method as an extension method of the string instance? e.g. accessing it with "text {0} text {1}".format(value1, value2); the benefit is having less code.

Comment: @William: https://gist.github.com/1096824

Comment: How to use the above code in the same way as I use extension methods in C#?