# Formatting the phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The below textbox is printing the value of the phone number after getting it from the database.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<s:textfield theme="simple" name="phoneNumber"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to print this value in the format (xxx) xxx-xxxx.
Note: The values are coming in the form of 0123456789 from the database 
and output should be (012)345-6789.

Comment: What is the server-side language? It'd be much easier to format the number server-side.

Comment: I am using struts2 framwork and java language.

Comment: for formatting strings in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery

Comment: Are the numbers in the DB all in the same format? Or do you have numbers like +41792359866 or 0041792359866 or +41-792-349-866 (i.e. japanese format vs nanp)

Comment: they all are in the format of 0123456789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
phone = "0123456789"
formated_phone = "("+phone.substring(0,3)+")"+phone.substring(3,6)+"-"+phone.substring(6,11)
```

Comment: Your expression  is generating exception

Comment: The expression "("+phone.substring(0,3)+")" in itself is giving exception. Null value is getting returned.

Comment: Try to convert your phone var to string.

Comment: It should be as follows: formatted_phone = '('+phone.substr(0,3)+') '+phone.substr(3,3)+'-'+phone.substr(6,4);

Answer (score 11):

I would prefer to use `replace` and `regexp` (less code, more features).

```
         var phone = "0123456789";
         phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/,"($1)$2-$3"); // (012)345-6789
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) => {
  // convert the raw number to (xxx) xxx-xxx format
  const x = phoneNumber && phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  return !x[2] ? x[1] : `(${x[1]}) ${x[2]}${x[3] ? `-${x[3]}` : ''}`;
};

console.log(formatPhoneNumber("1111111111"));
```