# jQuery Variable with .css() concatenation issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change CSS of a button on blur. I suspect it might be a concatenation issue but am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is my code...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="blue" id="textinput">
<button>Button</button>
<span id="color">red</span>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
 background-color:blue;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, black 100%);    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#textinput").blur(function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
          endColor = $("#textinput").val();
          $('button').css({ 
              'background-color' : endColor
              'background-image' : '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #309ACB 0%,' + endColor + '100%)'       });
     }, 500);
});​
```

**FIDDLE LINK**

http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/p2jah/20/

It works fine when I remove the gradient CSS. So I am guessing I am concatenating the variable wrong. However I have tried it multiple ways but just can't seem to figure it out. It is probably something really obvious.

Also note. I am using webkit gradient so test in chrome or safari. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a **whitespace** between your variable holding the color and the percentage string.

```
'-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #309ACB 0%,' + endColor + ' 100%)'
                                                        ^
                                                        |
                                                        +-- Here
```

A good way to debug this kind of situations is to use `console.log` to see the result of the concatenated string. In this case, for example, you'd get `red100%` instead of `red 100%`.

An alternative, which imho, is less error-prone, is to use `String.format()`. This way, you can (more) clearly see if you are missing something:

```
'-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #309ACB 0%, {0} 100%)'.format(endColor)
```

<sub>Note that some browsers don't support this function, but you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038930/140816) pollyfill to define it.</sub>

Comment: Yep that is what it was. I have been looking at this for a good half hour and didn't pick that up. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: You're welcome. An alternative, which is less error-prone, is to use `format`. For example: `'-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #309ACB 0%, {0} 100%)'.format("red")`. This way, you can easily see where the spaces are.

Comment: I have never used .format() before.. Thanks for the info. I didn't even know that was part of the jQuery library.

Comment: It's not. It's pure JavaScript, although some browsers don't support it. However, you can easily create it http://stackoverflow.com/a/1038930/140816.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a comma, and space (see Joao's answer)

```
$("#textinput").blur(function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
          endColor = $("#textinput").val();
          $('button').css({ 
              'background-color' : endColor, // < here        -> this way too               v here
              'background-image' : '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #309ACB 0%,' + endColor + ' 100%)'       });
     }, 500);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks.. I acutally had the comma in there before. That was a copy mistake  on my part. I forgot to add it back in when messing around in my fiddle. However the whitespace is what was actually causing the problem...