# Are there any string formatting functions built into jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#stats-list")
    .append("<li>Elapsed: " + ajaxElapsed + "</li>\n" +
            "<li>Display: " + tableElapsed + "</li>\n" +
            "<li>Total:   " + (ajaxElapsed + tableElapsed) + "</li>");
```

This was originally three appends that I concatenated into one. Is there anything I could do with jQuery that would clean up this code even more. What I was wondering was if jQuery has any string formatting with tokens that I could use.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery look like what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function format(formatString) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
    return formatString.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(match, num) {
      return args[Number(num)];
    });
}

format("<li>Elapsed: {0}</li>\n<li>Display: {1}</li>\n<li>Total:   {2}</li>",
    ajaxElapsed, tableElapsed, ajaxElapsed + tableElapsed);
```

Comment: Any ideas why format is not there as part of javascript core functionality?

Comment: Ecma did probably not consider it necessary. It's easy to implement yourself, as you see above.

Answer (score 1):

afaik there is none built-in, but a powerful templating-subsystem, see [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)

just for completeness, i think this could be done more elegant:

```
var list = $('#stats-list');
$('<li />').text('Elapsed: ' + ajaxElapsed).appendTo(list);
$('<li />').text('Display: ' + tableElapsed).appendTo(list);
$('<li />').text('Total: ' + (ajaxElapsed + tableElapsed)).appendTo(list);
```

Comment: Do you think I could use javascript formatting instead? I've almost no knowledge of javascript so I will have to look into that?

Answer (score 1):

If you have many items you can do something like this to avoid missing `+` and writing `li` so many times. You can add any number of items inside the array and they will be joined with `li`s appropriately.

```
var list = '<li>' + [
  'Elapsed: ' + ajaxElapsed,
  'Display: ' + tableElapsed,
  'Total: ' + ajaxElapsed + tableElapsed
].join('</li><li>') + '</li>';

$("#stats-list").append(list);
```

As a note I wouldn't use `\n`. `li` is a block element by default, so you'd be better styling it with css.