# JS How to include a variable in a path?

Tags: javascript

The following variable contains a string that is a path to an image.

```
iconBlue.image = 'http://www.site.com/icon1.jpg';
```

How can include a variable in this path? Let me explain more detailed. Lets say there are many icons in a folder icon1.jpg icon2.jpg etc. I have a variable named iconspec that depending on its value (1 or 2 or 3 etc) points to the icon I must use.

How can i include variable iconspec  in the path?

```
iconBlue.image='http://www.site.com/icon"iconspec".jpg
```

Something like this i guess but with correct syntax.

Comment: `iconBlue.image='httl://www.site.com/icon'+iconspec+'.jpg'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iconBlue.image='http://www.site.com/icon'+iconspec+'.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put it like a simple string with variable.

In your case, you should do this:

```
iconBlue.image = 'http://www.site.com/icon'+iconspec+'.jpg';
```

The `+` operator is like the `.` in PHP, it merge string.

Answer (score 0):

To take a little different route, you could encapsulate the concatenation in a function and make it a bit more reusable:

```
var icon = function(){
    this.path = '';
    this.imageName = '';

    this.imagePath = function() { return this.path + '/' + this.imageName };
};


var iconBlue = new icon(),
    iconRed = new icon();
iconBlue.path = "c:\\stuff";
iconBlue.imageName = "icon1.jpg";

iconRed.path="c:\\morestuff";
iconRed.imageName = "icon2.jpg";

alert(iconBlue.imagePath());
alert(iconRed.imagePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use the `+` to concatenate the variable to the string:

```
var name = 'sachleen';
var result = 'my name is ' + name;

Output: my name is sachleen
```

There are a couple of more powerful options available as well.

[JavaScript sprintf()](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) is a `sprintf` implementation for JS.

[string.format in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using template literals:

```
iconBlue.image = `http://www.yoursitehere.com/icon${iconspec}.jpg`;
```

Inside the backticks `` you can use ${} with the variable name to use a variable in a string.