# .net's string.format() in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)
>   [Equivalent of String.format in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

Is there any built javascript or jquery function that behaives like .net's in string.format()?

Or like javascript's console.log string repclament?

console.log('aString %s', 'valueToReplace')

Comment: A few minutes with Google, looking for `Javascript string format` yields many hits.  If that isn't powerful enough, there is a `Javascript sprintf` which is far more powerful.

Comment: My question was if there is a built in solution, why do you rate my question baddly?

Comment: Because a few minutes of Googling would have answered your question.  All of the build-in Javascript functions and methods are well documented -- [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference) is one such reference.  Though I don't use jQuery, it has a well documented API as well.

Comment: Whatever, what's the point of having a site like this then? You can alway read documentation and lots of stuff. It has no sense what you said. Am I supposed to search all the API documentation before asking a question?

Comment: The idea that you'd consider coding **without** reading the entire API documentation amazes me.

Comment: I'd be amazed if you had a life apart from work. I can't read the complete documentation of every technology I start to work with, lucky you! Here's a tip, print your stack's profile page and bring it with you to a club ;) I'm kitting, you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native solution, but here is one of many partial solutions: http://monocleglobe.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/everybody-needs-a-little-printf-in-their-javascript/