# Jquery string format issue with {0}

Tags: jquery

This not works and I can't figure it out why...

```
alert("milan {0}".format("djukic"));
```

My `jquery` version is 1.6.2.
I tried everything and no success..

Comment: What exactly you want to do? this does not explain at all!

Comment: This is not related to jQuery, you are calling an undefined method. What is `format`?

Comment: I want to print "milan djukic"

Comment: there is no predefined method called `.format()` in jQuery.  I guess are you using any external plugins or have you written any method?

Comment: Now i see that format is not standard function.. Is there any like this or must write one? i want some method for string formating

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't an error related to jQuery - it's the fact that you're trying to run a string instance's  method that doesn't exist. A quick search gives me [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery), which happily implements `String#format` for you.

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var str = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {       
    var reg = new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "gm");             
    str = str.replace(reg, arguments[i]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Just paste that at the top or near to the top of your script file and use your newly-created function like `"the {0} jumps over the {1}".format("quick brown fox", "lazy dog");` in the script.

Comment: There's a small error there. The related answer implements `String.format`, that is, as a static method which takes a string as the first argument. To implement `String.prototype.format` you'd have to replace `arguments[0]` with `this`.

Comment: Uhm I believe you can't reassign a value to `this` that way, better keep the `var s = this;` I think. `:P`

Comment: I did that too. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! Very nice function!