# How to augment actionlink with route values at runtime with JavaScript in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this ActionLink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "action", "controller", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "menuLink"})
```

I have to set routeValues to `null` because I don't know the value at compiletime. They are recieved from the selectedvalue of some dropdowns at runtime.

Hence, I am trying to augment the routevalues at runtime with JavaScript. I can't see what other choise I have.

I use the CSS class `menuLink` on the ActionLink to catch the event.

```
$(".menuLink").click(function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        routeValue1 = getFromDropdown1(),
        routeValue2 = getFromDropdown2(),
        href = $self.attr("href");

     // ???
});
```

How can I add the routevalues to make the href correct?

I want the URL to be something like this:

`http://localhost/mySite/controller/action/2/2`

My focus is on the `/2/2` part..

I have tryed this

```
$self.attr("foo", routeValue1);
$self.attr("bar", routeValue2);
```

But then I get a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/mySite/controller/action?foo=2&bar=2
```

And it doesn't work with my routes.MapeRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Authenticated",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{foo}/{bar}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "WelcomePage", Foo = "0", Bar = "0" }
);
```

I don't know if `Foo = "0", Bar = "0"` is the problem.

**Solution added. Thanks to @Zabavsky**

```
if (!String.format) {
    String.format = function (format) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
                ? args[number]
                : match
            ;
        });
    };
}

var href = $self.attr("href");
var hrefDecoded = decodeURIComponent(href);
var hrefFormatted = String.format(hrefDecoded, 2, 1); // 2 and 1 test only..
$self.attr('href', hrefFormatted);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way of doing this, but I'll provide you with my solution to this problem. The main idea is to generate the link with all required parameters and format the `href` with javascript, like `string.Format` in c#.

> 1. Generate the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "action", "controller",
    new { Foo = "{0}", Bar = "{1}"}, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "menuLink" })
```

The helper will generate the correct url, which according to your route configuration will look like this:

```
<a href="http://website.com/controller/action/{0}/{1}" class="menuLink">Link</a>
```

> 2. Write the `format` function.

You can check how to implement one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1038746/1199711). If you are using jQuery validation plugin you can utilize the built in [format function](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.format/).

> 3. Format `href` attribute in your javascript:

```
$(".menuLink").click(function () {
    var routeValue1 = getFromDropdown1(),
        routeValue2 = getFromDropdown2(),
        url = decodeURIComponent(this.href);

    // {0} and {1} will be replaced with routeValue1 and routeValue1
    this.href = url.format(routeValue1, routeValue2);
});
```

**Do not** concatenate route parameters to the href like this `href +'/'+ routeValue1  +'/'+routeValue2`, the url will result in 404 if you change your route configuration. You should always generate urls with Url helpers and avoid hadcoding them in the javascript code.

Comment: That's what I am trying to accomplish. Use helpers the right way and have a less javascript in use as possible. I like your solution where you really take advanges of the format method.

Comment: Do I need to augment the String.prototype with the method format first for this to work, like this? Do you have that already?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Comment: You can implement it in any way you want, I just gave you the idea.

Comment: I just want to understand if I have `format` already or need to do something about it.

Comment: I don't think you have format already, unless you are using jQuery validation. You have to implement it based on the samples I gave or those you found by yourself, which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I can't make it work, do you mind helping me more? alert('href before: ' + $self.attr("href")); Gives: "href before: /mysite/controller/action/%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D". Also what format method do you reccommend? I tryed both but it doesn't work. Maybe because my href has "%7B0%7D/%7B1%7D" and not "{0}/{1}".. How do I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @radbyx, yes, I forgot that you have to decode the `href` before formatting it using `decodeURIComponent` function. Check my edit.

Comment: Yes you have, it's a javascript function.

Comment: Thanks that decode worked. Now I have the error "format is not a function" problem even though tryed to add if (!String.format) {
  String.format = function(format) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number] 
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
} just before i used it. But at least im getting closer. I never tryed to augment String or something before.. just read about it could be done, if you are missing some handy JS function. :)

Comment: So finally got it. Big thanks man. I have added the solution for others.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the href attribute of anchor tag dynamically like below.

```
$(".menuLink").click(function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        routeValue1 = getFromDropdown1(),
        routeValue2 = getFromDropdown2(),
        href = $self.attr("href"),
        editedHref = href.split('?')[0];

    $self.attr('href', editedHref+'/'+ routeValue1  +'/'+routeValue2 );
});
```

Comment: Does't seem to work i get http://localhost/mysite/controller/action?foo=2&bar=2/2/2