# jquery replace text between brackets

Tags: jquery, arrays, replace

I have an array like

```
data['name']='Alex';
data['age']='21';
```

and a string like

```
var text='My name is {name} and my age is {age}';
```

How to replace the data between brackets with corresponding array value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of String.format in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038746/equivalent-of-string-format-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpolate variables in strings in JavaScript, without concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304014/how-to-interpolate-variables-in-strings-in-javascript-without-concatenation)

Comment: you can do this in JavaScript now using template string `var text = \`My name is ${data.name} and my age is ${data.age}\`;` check details [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a function to replace

```js
var text = 'My name is {name} and my age is {age}';
var data = {
  name: 'foo',
  age: 18
}

let res = text.replace(/\{(\w+)\}/g, (_, g) => data[g]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through your array and get the name and age.

```js
var data = [{'name':'Alex','age':'18'}];
var text = '';
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   text = "My name is "+ data[i].name+" and my age is "+ data[i].age+" .";
}

console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in JavaScript using template string

```
// Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)
data['name']='Alex';
data['age']='21';
var text = `My name is ${data.name} and my age is ${data.age}`;
```

check details [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [];

data['name']='Alex';
data['age']='21';

var text='My name is {name} and my age is {age}';

var result = formatString(text, data); // desired output
console.log(result);

/* Replace the token values */
function formatString(text, data)
{
    var keyNames = Object.keys(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < keyNames.length ;i++)
    {
        text = text.replace("{"+ keyNames[i] +"}", data[ keyNames[i] ] );
    }
    return text;
}
```